# Unable to check received value on serial port in Matlab

Tags: matlab, serial-port, char, usart

I want to check if I receive a dot ('.') on serial port in Matlab. For this I run for loop for 10 times in which I check if  I got '.' on serial port then display "A dot is received" otherwise display whatever is receive. But on receiving '.' on serial port it is not displaying "A dot is receibed". Here is my code:-

```
s=serial('COM5', 'BaudRate',9600);%, 'DataBits',8, 'Terminator','');
fopen(s);
disp('Port succefully Opened');
count=0;
checkdot = '.';
for x = 1:10

       recv= fscanf(s);
z = char(recv);
    if (z== '.')
        disp('A dot is received');

    else
        disp(z);
end

end
fclose(s);
```

And here is my output on command window:-

```
>> Serialcomm
Port succefully Opened
.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.
```

So, please tell me where is the mistake.

Comment: maybe try using `strcmp`: if strcmp(z,'.'). There may also be some other characters received that you can't necessarily see, such as a carriage return or new line character.

Comment: am304: I tried, but it doesn't work

Comment: You need to check for carriage return (`'\r'`) and new line characters (`'\n'`) also, e.g. `if strcmp(z,'.\r\n')`. In fact looking at the output of `disp`, it looks like you have may have two new line characters: `if strcmp(z,'.\r\n\n')`. You need to experiment until you find the correct set of characters, it not only the dot.

Comment: I tried , but still nothing happens

Comment: Could you add  `disp(double(z))` below the `disp(z)` a and run it again? That displays all caracters as double so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `deblank` (removes all whitespace characters) or `strtrim` (removes only leading and trailing whitespace) to get rid of unwanted characters:

```
a = sprintf('.\r\n');
disp(a)
.

strcmp(a,'.')
ans =

     0
strcmp(strtrim(a),'.')
ans =

     1
```

Also, you're using `fscanf` to retrieve data from the serial port, try using `fgetl` instead. `fgetl` gets one line and discards terminators, so should only retrieve the `.` (in theory).